# Unable to click on tooltip link using selenium webdriver java

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, tooltip

I have to click on tooltip which then opens a popup. I am unable to click on it and i get an error - no such element found.

Can anyone please help me on this. I'm sure im making some mistake in xpath.

[image]

Comment: Can you consider working on the Answers provided by the SO volunteers at your previous Questions, work on them & Accept/Close them before asking a new Question? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB I am new to stackoverflow so i dont know how to Accept/Close my questions. If you could tell me how do to it, it would be helpful. If I have different set of questions then I would post it instead of waiting for one to be resolved. Thanks

Comment: @santhoshkumar Thanks. I'll try with mouse over option and see if it works. I thought its my xpath issue

Comment: @santhoshkumar Not working. Still says 'no such element found'

Comment: Actions builder = mew Actions(driver)  WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"))  builder.moveToElement(element).click().perform()  Am I using the right method @santhoshkumar

Comment: Once I click on tooltip it should open a pop up. But in first place im still unable to click on tooltip. I used the xpath as - //*[@id="vanilla"]/fed-lab/div/getting-started/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/creditcards-calculators/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/button/span @santhoshkumar

Comment: @santhoshkumar Yea just checked on console and its correct as it returns 1 matching node.

Comment: Is the xpath that you have written is for the expanded tool tip?. Can I have the URL to help you better

Comment: @santhoshkumar I checked xpath in xpath checker and it gave me the tooltip . So my xpath is accurate for sure. I also tried using implicit wait and also tried visibilityofelementlocated method. Nothing works );

Comment: @santhoshkumar  On the tooltip next to 'Balance to transfer'  On left  which falls under 'Calculate potential savings' category. Let me know if you have found it!

Comment: @santhoshkumar Did this xpath work for you? I tried finding the element by your xpath and clicking on it. But still it says element not found );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/santhoshkumar/Softwares/Selenium/drivers/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://compare.giffgaff.com/creditcards#/results/zeroPercentBalanceTransfer");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[contains(text(),'Calculate potential savings')]/parent::div/div[1]//div[@class='c-tooltip']//span")).click();
}
```